# IIS 7 long timeout on individual PHP script

Tags: php, iis-7

I know there was some trick with the metabase in IIS 6 to do this, but 7 is different.

Basically, I have a long-running PHP script that handles its own timeout in the regular PHP way, that keeps getting killed by the server before it's done. I need the IIS 7 procedure for giving it a long or no timeout on *just that one script* and no others.

Answer (score 0):

check set_time_limit function.

set_time_limit(0); //will remove execution time limit

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Already does that, see line 2 of question. It's IIS that's killing the thread, because this was fixed in version 6, but now I'm using 7.